# What engine should I use to create 2D minigames?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, game-development

I want to start programming 2D games and I don't know what engine I should use (I work on my own and I am a beginner; plus I'm very young).

I've tried [Kodu](http://www.kodugamelab.com/) but it doesn't have a lot of possibilities and it crashes a lot. I also tried [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) but it is too complex even though it says it is for beginners.

Here is my list of requirements:

- Free
- For beginners (not very complex)
- Offers a lot of possibilities for programming (2D) games
- Has a simple interface that is easy to work on
- Offers help and tutorials if any difficulties (optional)
- Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [Pygame](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyGame)

Python is a high-level programming language. It is beginner friendly and its codes are intuitive and very readable, you can get the Windows setup [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Pygame is an easy to use Python library for writing games. You can get the latest setup [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) (and *not* on the main site pygame.org)

As for the learning part, I suggest that you start with [Invent with Python](http://inventwithpython.com/). It has three detailed books that are targeted towards beginners, and you can download them for free. The [first one](http://inventwithpython.com/inventwithpython.pdf) is about the Python syntax, and the [second](http://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf) is focused on Pygame. They come with a complete set of example games along with detailed code explanation and instructions.

Regarding your requirements:

- Python and Pygame are both free
- Lots of examples online and the ability to create any 2D game you put your mind into
- Simple interface: you can code it with your favorite text editor, and run with the `python` command. Or simply use IDLE, the IDE packaged with Python
- Has beginner friendly tutorials linked above
- Is cross-platform and runs on Windows

Comment: Forgot to mention that both python and pygame are FREE! Both an advantage and a question requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [GameMakerStudio](http://www.yoyogames.com/).

- free for Windows
- strong in 2D games development
- simpler to pick up than Unity (if you are starting to code)
- there are many tutorials, although not official videos like the Unity ones
- provides a simple interface (has its own code editor and all)
- has [a nice community](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/)

You can start coding with blocks and then learn GML (Game Maker Language) to code like a pro.